Secure the URL link?
I'm trying to use a cloud to save & load my data. It's working, but the URL link is readable. Is there a way to hide/secure it after exporting the game?

A user could always run a tool like Wireshark to peek at their network traffic and see where messages are being sent to. The bigger question is why would seeing the URL be a problem? There may be a deeper issue here that you can solve at the root, rather than trying to obscure it.

There are as well different types of urls. There is a difference between randomEndpoint.com/rshdfn84msdflk45 vs randomEndpoint.com/userName=abc&pw=def&myData=123. Usually you have a server inbetween that handles the actual communication (also for reasons like limiting cloud calls)

No. You could obfuscate it, but you can not hide it. In order to access the server, the game must be able to decode it. In order to decode it, it needs the decryption key and decryption algorithm. If the game has this information, then a determined hacker can find it.
Further, a determined hacker could use a tool to sniff on the network traffic generated by your game and find those HTTP requests and what URL they are going to.
If your game needs server-sided storage then what you would usually do is:

Put it behind a web API that only allows controlled and limited access to the data
Have players create personalized accounts with username and password, so they can only access their own data. Or alternatively, use the APIs of your distribution platform (app store, steam...) to link users to their store accounts and use that for authentication with your API

